# Sharing git repo without SSH

Tags: authentication, git

I'm trying to set-up a private git repo for code sharing, but found out that most of the implementations out there require use of SSH public keys, for example:

http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/

The only approach looking reasonable is the git-daemon, but it does not contain any authentication, and while it might be a good option for LAN, it is no go for remote working.

Coming from SVN daemon, where all the access was conveniently controlled via single file, the SSH keys scheme quite a hurdle for me.

Is there any way to securely share multiple Git repositories, without using SSH authentication?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is SSH not an option for you? Once you get your head wrapped around it, it's incredibly simple to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH auth is the most common way to do this.  Even though it seems a bit complex to you, try taking a look at something called 'gitolite'.  It makes the process pretty straightforward (You basically have one file that is similar to a standard SVN authz file, and another directory full of SSH keys).

I don't think there's any other way to do this, everything relies on SSH keys because it's a reliable way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Gitosis ( http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way ). It's an easy way to host git repos. It uses SSH to authenticate, but doesn't allow the user full SSH access to the host.